# How to remove layers by name - openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I was add vector layer with `wkt` source to map with below code:

```
var SelectVector = null;
```

`for (var i = 0; i < wktarray.length; i++) { 
   var wkt = wktarray[i];
   var format = new ol.format.WKT();
   var feature = format.readFeature(wkt, {
       dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
        featureProjection: 'EPSG:4326'
    });`

`SelectVector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
            features: [feature]
        }),style: new ol.style.Style({
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
            }),  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#ffcc33',                 width: 2
            }), image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: '#ffcc33'
                })
            })
        })
    });`

```
map.addLayer(SelectVector);
SelectVector.set('name', 'selectvector');
}
```

Now, I want remove this vector layer from map. wrote below code but, it does not remove all layer with `selectvector` name.

```
map.getLayers().forEach(function (layer) {
    if (layer.get('name') != undefined & layer.get('name') === 'selectvector') {
        map.removeLayer(layer);
    }
});
```

what is wrong?

Comment: be sure of layer value is your selected layer, for example write to console and check it

Comment: and condition should be && not &